# CMake fails with "did not find file compiler/msvc-asm" even though it exists

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to generate Visual Studio project files with CMake. I'm executing the following command in the Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -Thost=x64 ../project
```

Everything is found correctly except the ASM compiler (which should be `cl.exe` which comes with Visual Studio). I find this weird because the C++ compiler, which is the exact same file, has been found!

For reference, I'm seeing this line in the log:

```
Warning: Did not find file Compiler/MSVC-ASM
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on VS2013 and solved it by using `enable_language(ASM_MASM)` instead of `enable_language(ASM)` and forcing the inclusion of the assembly code file with `set_property(SOURCE <file>.S PROPERTY LANGUAGE ASM_MASM)` otherwise the file would not participate in the build.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know why this happens, but it looks like the developer command prompt messes up something which CMake uses to find the ASM compiler.

This worked for me:

1. Make sure that `cl.exe` is in your PATH (and any other relevant file which your project uses).
2. Execute the command in the regular command prompt (or the Native Tools one).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out `MSVC-ASM` is the name of an actual CMake module.
I'm using CMake 3.8.2, and in my case it was indeed missing!

`MSVC-ASM.cmake` a placeholder for settings to be used for the Visual Studio assembler. It may be just an empty file:
https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/MSVC-ASM.cmake

I was able to track it down using CMake's `--trace` option.
It's being included by another file, `CMakeASMInformation.cmake`, and if not found, that warning is printed:

```
# Load compiler-specific information.
set(_INCLUDED_FILE "")
if(CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_COMPILER_ID)
  include(Compiler/${CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_COMPILER_ID}-ASM${ASM_DIALECT} OPTIONAL  RESULT_VARIABLE _INCLUDED_FILE)
endif()
if(NOT _INCLUDED_FILE)
  if("ASM${ASM_DIALECT}" STREQUAL "ASM")
    message(STATUS "Warning: Did not find file Compiler/${CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_COMPILER_ID}-ASM${ASM_DIALECT}")
  endif()
  include(Platform/${CMAKE_BASE_NAME} OPTIONAL)
endif()
```

**Solution:** created an empty `MSVC-ASM.cmake` under `c:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.8\Modules\Compiler`, and viola, the warning was gone.

Answer (score -1):

You have too old version of CMake... The required file was missing in older versions...